# How do I change all URLs that contain underscores to dashes but only for one directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on a live site, so I don't want to create any server errors by making a mistake.  I need to change all URLs that contain underscores to dashes but only for one directory (www.domain.com/directory/), but I do not want to change images, css, or js files.

All I got so far for my .htaccess is:

```
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*_.*) $1-$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

But I don't know how to specify this rule for a specific only and exclude my images, css, and javascript files.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To limit the rule to certain requests, you'll need to use `RewriteCond`. You can find the documentation on those [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond).

To only let it work for `www.domain.com/directory/` you can add this to the RewriteRule itself. Please note that you are using a permanent redirect, so any change you currently will make will not work until you clear the cache from the browser for your site.

```
RewriteRule ^directory/([^_]*)_([^_]*_.*) /directory/$1-$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^directory/([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /directory/$1-$2 [L,R]
```

To exclude css and js files, you can use something like this. This will exclude (`!`) files that end on `.css` or `.js` (`\.(css|js)`).

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js)$
RewriteRule ^directory/([^_]*)_([^_]*_.*) /directory/$1-$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^directory/([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /directory/$1-$2 [L,R]
```

I can't test these rules and I encourage you to set up a simple localhost server to test things on before doing them on your live site. If you are testing redirects on a site, *always* use temporary redirects (`[R]`) instead of permanent redirects (`[R=301]`). Permanent redirects are cached by the browser and reduce the load on the server for subsequent requests, but if you are testing, it will remember a previous attempt. Only change temporary redirects to permanent redirects after all rules work as you want them to work.

Comment: I added the code to my .htaccess file and cleared my cache, but my URLs are still not being changed from _ to -.  Any other suggestions, @Sumurai8 ?

Comment: This is a case of [works for me](http://www.screenr.com/IpzH). Check for conflicting rules. Try it in an other browser if needed. Inspect the requests in the developer console of the browser. Maybe you notice something strange there.

Comment: Thanks @Sumurai8  I moved the rules to the .htaccess inside the directory that I was trying to change and it worked.  Thank you for your feedback!